# Visual Studio weird display bug with ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I add a line break, it produces following display bug:

[image]

It takes a long time until everything is refreshed. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional. **It seems to only occur when ReSharper is enabled.**

Comment: Do you have access to another machine with it installed to see if it always happens?

Comment: @JeffS No, but it seemed to randomly appear a few weeks ago. I've reinstalled Visual Studio and ReSharper multiple times already.

Comment: Try to disable hardware acceleration (rendering) in Visual Studio or play with the settings (Settings->Environment->General->Visual experience)

Comment: @aLightning it appears others have noticed resharper running slowly, read this for some suggestions http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104498-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow you could also try Rinecamo's suggestion